# SQL Regex Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch all the IDs in SQL that matches the following parameters, the IDs look like these `LLL-DDDDD`

- LLL has 1 to 3 letters in it
- DDDDD has 3 to 5 digits in it

Its usually an ID like A-12345 or AA-12345 or AAA-12345

I think I'd have to write a REGEX expression for the same, can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Are they actually surrounded by parenthesis, or no? That would make regex easier.

Comment: Hello, have you tried looking into LIKE or PATINDEX using wildcards "[]" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: this would be a really slow query as it will need to process the data row by row on a string function... I would suggest a different design if you have large amounts of data

Comment: They are not surrounded by parenthesis, I edited the question with few examples. Thanks for the help.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support (real) regular expressions.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I tried using multiple like statements but I guess its not really efficient/flexible. I am working on integrating a .NET code with SQL. I will definitely post here once I am finished. I approached Stack overflow to ask if there's an easier approach since I have never used .NET before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from
(
values ('ABC-12345'), ('AB-123'), ('A-12345'), ('A1B-1234'), ('ABC12345'), ('xyz-12'), ('klmno-12345'), ('abc.12345')
) as t(v)
where v like '[A-Z]%-%[0-9]' --values start with letter & contain a hyphen & end with a digit
--left part
and len(substring(v, 1, charindex('-', v)-1)) between 1 and 3 --the left part is 1-3 chars long
and substring(v, 1, charindex('-', v)-1) not like '%[^A-Z]%'--the left part has only letters
--right part
and len(stuff(v, 1, charindex('-', v), '')) between 3 and 5 --right part is 3-5 chars long
and stuff(v, 1, charindex('-', v), '') not like '%[^0-9]%'; --and it contains only digits
```

Comment: Many thanks Dale, it looks like this is working. I was looking for something like this so I don't have to switch to .NET  function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it all in one regex. But if you can split at the `()` then you can separately query `LLL` and `DDDDD`

For 1-3 letters use `/[a-zA-Z]{3,5}/g`

For 3-5 digits use `/\d{3,5}/g`

Answer (score 0):

The full regex would be `^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{3,5}$`, but SQL Server does not support complete regex syntax. You can pattern match the letter[s] or numbers, but not their quantity, so you'll need a terrible WHERE query to include your variations.

If a hyphen is *sometimes* present and sometimes not, you should remove the potential hyphen with a REPLACE() around your column, to avoid doubling the number of statements in your WHERE clause.

```sql
select * 
from @test 
where 
    /* 1 letter, 3-5 digits */
    col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

    /* 2 letters, 3-5 digits */
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

    /* 3 letters, 3-5 digits */
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][a-zA-z][a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][a-zA-z][a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
    or col1 LIKE '[a-zA-z][a-zA-z][a-zA-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this code is very lengthy and not very flexible. I may have to try creating a function like the one in the link below, but I thought that maybe there's a simpler approach to it:

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/february/sql-server-regular-expressions-for-efficient-sql-querying

Comment: A limitation of the DB in question, regrettably, and not a byproduct of poor coding. I believe Oracle and Postgres handle regex natively. Best of luck on integrating .NET; it will open many doors, including the ability to use full Regex expressions.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions.  This would be easy if it did (`'^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}-[0-9]{3,5}$').  In the most recent versions, you can use python or R extensions to do regular expressions, but this may not be too bad with existing string operations.

I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (values (left(id, charindex('-', id + '-') - 1),
              stuff(id, 1, charindex('-', id + '-'), '')
             )
     ) v(part1, part2)
where part1 not like '%[^A-Za-z]%' and
      len(part1) between 1 and 3 and
      part2 not like '%[^0-9]%' and
      len(part2) between 3 and 5;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/103359) is a little SQL FIddle.